# php - Strange contants in DateTimeZone class

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

There is strange constants in DateTimeZone class

```
class DateTimeZone {

    const UTC = 1024;
    const ALL = 2047;
    ...
}
```

I have tried to find any information about them. Also have tried to use them:

```
$dtz = new DateTimeZone(DateTimeZone::UTC); // throws Exception with message 
                                            // DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (1024)
```

or

```
$dt = new Datetime('2016-02-01 10:00:00', DateTimeZone::UTC); // throws Exception with message
                                                              // DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeZone, integer given
```

What are they for and how to use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're used in a few spots, like `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers`, which takes stuff like `DateTimeZone::EUROPE` as an argument (and would give you a list of all the `Europe/Whatever` timezones).

You can't use them to create a `DateTimeZone` or `DateTime` because they're regional groups of multiple timezones, not specific individual timezones (the UTC one may have confused you here).